# Access SQL Query Date

Tags: ms-access

Here is my code:

```
SELECT DataBaseUser.Agents, Abs(Sum([NoPPI1])) AS [NoPPI-1], Abs(Sum([NoPPI2])) AS [NoPPI-2], Abs(Sum([NoPPI3])) AS [NoPPI-3], Abs(Sum([NoPPI4])) AS [NoPPI-4], Abs(Sum([NoPPI5])) AS [NoPPI-5], Abs(Sum([NoPPI6])) AS [NoPPI-6], Abs(Sum([NoPPI1])+Sum([NoPPI2])+Sum([NoPPI3])+Sum([NoPPI4])+Sum([NoPPI5])+Sum([NoPPI6])) AS TotalNoPPI
FROM DataBaseUser INNER JOIN MainData ON DataBaseUser.ID = MainData.AgentDropDown
GROUP BY DataBaseUser.Agents;
```

Trying to get this query to work, basically the query is summing up the total NoPPI1 through to NoPPI6 for each sales agent. The problem I have is I need there to be some kind of filter on NoPPI1 for say this month, and then for NoPPI2 a date filter for say 2 months ago.

Is this possible?

Thanks

---

Update

The result at the moment looks like this:

```
Agents | NoPPI1 | NoPPI2 | NoPPI3 | NoPPI4 | NoPPI5 | NoPPI6 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
Ash    | 34     | 32     | 17     | 12     | 4      | 1      |
Kate   | 45     | 23     | 15     | 9      | 2      | 0      |
```

etc..  |

The field that would control the date is NoPPIDate1 etc..

So what I am trying to achieve is:

NoPPI1 needs to be summed, and abs and then filtered by date, and then the same for the other but a different date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the general, (relevant) structure of the database as well as a brief summery what information you want to extract. It's just easier for us to help you if we don't have to reverse-engineer your query ^^

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to normalize the table with a UNION query. This will give you much more control:

```
SELECT Agent, "NoPPI1" As Description, NoPPI1 As NoPPI,  NoPPI1Date As NoPPIDate
FROM Table
UNION
SELECT Agent, "NoPPI2" As Description, NoPPI2 As NoPPI,  NoPPI2Date As NoPPIDate
FROM Table
<...>
```

You can then select more easily:

```
SELECT Agent, Sum(NoPPI) FROM UnionQ
WHERE NoPPIDate=#2012/12/31#
GROUP BY Agent
```